# What is the point of getElementById when JS finds elements by name anyway

Tags: javascript

If there is an HTML element with id="hello123", then this JS code prints the content of the element: `console.log(hello123.innterHTML)`

```js
console.log(hello123.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="hello123">hello this works 123</p>
```

I discovered this by happenstance, I would other wise have written:

```
hello123 = document.getElementById("hello123);
console.log(hello123.innerHTML);
```

What is the difference between the two? Is using getElementById better because it protects be in the case that hello123 is a variable already defined elsewhere that has nothing to do with an HTML element called hello123?

Comment: Try adding `const hello123 = "world"` and see what happens. Or try `<p id="hello-world></p>` in your HTML and try addressing it by the "name" directly.

Comment: Ok, hello-world.innerHTML does not work (returns "hello is not defined").

And I guess your first example was to show that if a variable with the same name already exists, then this does not work (returns undefined)?

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues That's because [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is a DOM property of a DOM object. See my answer below.

Comment: That's because `hello-world` is an expression meaning "subtract the value of the identifier `world` from the value of the identifier `hello`". Same as how you'd have `4 - 3` or `a - b`.  Basically the same problem with `hello-world.innerHTML` but it's the value of the `innerHTML` property of the `world` identifier` that's taken.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with an `id` become Global properties of the `window` object in the [Browser's Object Model (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Object_Model). It is not "JavaScript" that makes this happen. Accessing an element with `getElementById()` uses the [Document Object Model (DOM) API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), which is standardized. The BOM is largely not standardized. Using the DOM is the best practice.